# STOP: c000021a {Fatal System Error} The initial session process or system process terminated unexpectedly

Tags: active-directory, boot, disaster-recovery, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I'm encountering such an error after expanding disk space on a virtual machine using Hyper-V.

> STOP: c000021a {Fatal System Error}
>
> The initial session process or system process terminated unexpectedly with a status of (0x00000000) (0xc000012d 0x001003f0).

The virtual server there is Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition, which is also Domain Controller. I've tried to repair Windows but there is no restore point, and using the command line.

I've tried the `sfc /SCANNOW /OFFBOOTDIR /OFFWINDIR` command, but I got the error `Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation`.

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317189

> Programs or Setup programs may schedule a file to be renamed on the next restart of Windows NT if the program is prevented from renaming a file because the file is in memory.
>
> Windows NT checks a registry key for file-rename operations to be completed early in the boot process. If the file-rename operation cannot be completed because the file or folder does not exist, the error message is generated.

Not pretty, but you have to remove registry keys that are trying to perform a delayed rename operation:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\ControlSetXXX\Control\Session Manager
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx
    PendingFileRenameOperations
```

Reading the knowledge base article you'd almost be better off installing a fresh server.

Comment: Is that NT4 specific?